# Copy directory structure with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, directory, copy

Is there a way of doing the following in PowerShell?

```
xcopy \\m1\C$\Online\*.config \\m2\C$\Config-Backup /s
```

I have tried this:

```
Copy-Item \\m1\C$\Online\* -Recurse -Destination \\m2\C$\Config-Backup -include *.config
```

But it does nothing, probably because there are no configuration files in the root. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use native PowerShell (with a third party .NET module :P) and also don't want to let long file paths (> 255 characters) halt the copy, you can use this:

```
# Import AlphaFS .NET module - http://alphafs.codeplex.com/
Import-Module C:\Path\To\AlphaFS\DLL\AlphaFS.dll

# Variables
$SourcePath = "C:\Temp"
$DestPath = "C:\Test"

# RecursePath function.
Function RecursePath([string]$SourcePath, [string]$DestPath){

    # for each subdirectory in the current directory..       
    [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::GetDirectories($SourcePath) | % {

        $ShortDirectory = $_
        $LongDirectory = [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Path]::GetLongPath($ShortDirectory)

        # Create the directory on the destination path.
        [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::CreateDirectory($LongDirectory.Replace($SourcePath, $DestPath))

        # For each file in the current directory..                                              
        [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::GetFiles($ShortDirectory) | % {

            $ShortFile = $_
            $LongFile = [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Path]::GetLongPath($ShortFile)

            # Copy the file to the destination path.                                                                       
            [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.File]::Copy($LongFile, $LongFile.Replace($SourcePath, $DestPath), $true)                             

        }

    # Loop.
    RecursePath $ShortDirectory $DestPath
    }
}

# Execute!
RecursePath $SourcePath $DestPath
```

Please note this code was stripped out of a much larger project of mine, but I gave it a quick test and it seems to work. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I am loosing faith in M$. This is ridiculous. I will stick with xcopy. It's simple terse and it works. Powershell belongs on thedailywtf.

Comment: Yep the AlphaFS project is excellent. We have big issues in our environment with long file paths on our group shares and this helped us overcome it nice and easily. At first I was writing native C# code, but then I realised you could call the DLLs directly from PowerShell (who knew :P). They have extensive documentation too, which is always a plus. I'm right in the middle of this stuff right now, so if you have any similar questions let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
Start-Process xcopy "\\m1\C$\Online\*.config \\m2\C$\Config-Backup /s" -NoNewWindow
```

:P

Answer (score 0):

The new AlphaFS 2.0 makes this really easy.

Example: Copy a directory recursively

```js
# Set copy options.
PS C:\> $copyOptions = [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.CopyOptions]::FailIfExists

# Set source and destination directories.
PS C:\> $source = 'C:\sourceDir'
PS C:\> $destination = 'C:\destinationDir'

# Copy directory recursively.
PS C:\> [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::Copy($source, $destination, $copyOptions)
```

[AlphaFS on GitHub](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS)

Answer (score 0):

Look into robocopy. It's not a native PowerShell command, but I call it from PowerShell scripts all the time. Works similarly to xcopy only it's way more powerful.

Comment: I have subsequently found robocopy. My feeling is that powershell failing to deliver a tree copy out of the box is pretty pathetic.